# How to create multi threading socket server C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a WinForms application C#. In here, I used TcpClient/Socket and NetworkStream. I have created multiple thread to handle sending/receiving from client/server. Assuming I'm forced to use TcpClient/Socket, I won't use other libraries or third-party.

I can initiate multiple threads, and manage server/client connection in each thread. At the beginning, when I initialize (press start button), can send/receive data between client/server.

For example: I have 2 servers/ports, they will listening connections from the client side.
Server A: 192.168.10.1/5555
Server B: 192.168.10.1/6666

After initialization, I received 2 connections from client to server. They're connected normal between client/server in each Thread. And some data send/receive at the beginning working well also, assuming server sending "Hello", and client reply "Ok. I'm fine", this way happened on separate threads, not overlapping each other.
192.168.10.1/5555 - 10.10.10.1/34546
192.168.10.1/6666 - 10.10.10.1/54632

After that, I proceeded to manually send data from server A 192.168.10.1/5555 to client 10.10.10.1/34546. For server A works normally, the client 10.10.10.1/34546 can receive data. But when I send information from server B 192.168.10.1/6666 to client 10.10.10.1/54632, It doesn't work although before that it received normal data at initialization.
I don't know what's happened with my case. It works well when initialized, can send/receive on each connection between client/server. After that, messages can still be sent only in ServerA, ServerB can no longer send

```
public class Conn
{
    private TcpListener listener;
    private Socket socket;
    private NetworkStream stream;

    public TcpListener CListener
    {
        get { return listener; }
        set { listener = value; }
    }
    public Socket CSocket
    {
        get { return socket; }
        set { socket = value; }
    }
    public NetworkStream CStream
    {
        get { return stream; }
        set { stream = value; }
    }
}
private List<Conn> conn_list = null;
private async void _start_multi(Conn connection, TcpListener listener_multi, Socket socket_multi, NetworkStream stream_multi, string _ip, int _port)
{
    try
    {
        listener_multi = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);
        connection.CListener = listener_multi; //create listener
        listener_multi.Start();
        socket_multi = listener_multi.AcceptSocket();
        connection.CSocket = socket_multi; //create socket
        socket_multi.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
        socket_multi.SendTimeout = 180000;
        socket_multi.ReceiveTimeout = 180000;
        stream_multi = new NetworkStream(socket_multi);
        connection.CStream = stream_multi; //create stream
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024 * 5];
            int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        rec_continute:
            numberOfBytesRead = stream_multi.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            byte[] bytes_real = new byte[numberOfBytesRead];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(myReadBuffer, 0, bytes_real, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
            if (bytes_real.Length != 0)
            {
                byte[] msg_temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString("HELLO"));
                stream_multi.Write(msg_temp, 0, msg_temp.Length);
                stream_multi.Flush();
                goto rec_continute;
            }
            if (bytes_real.Length == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Warning" + ex.Message);
    }
}
private void bt_turnon_multi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dgv_multi_ip.Rows.Add("192.168.10.1", "5555");
        dgv_multi_ip.Rows.Add("192.168.10.1", "6666");
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_multi_ip.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var ip = dgv_multi_ip.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            var port = int.Parse(dgv_multi_ip.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            var connection = conn_list[i];
            TcpListener listener_multi = null;
            Socket socket_multi = null;
            NetworkStream stream_multi = null;
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                _start_multi(connection, listener_multi, socket_multi, stream_multi, ip, port);
            });
            thread.Start();
        }
}
private async Task send_msg_multi(Conn connection)
{
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString("ARE YOU OK?"));
    try
    {
        connection.CStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
        connection.CStream.Flush();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can not send msg" + ex.Message);
    }
}
private async void bt_send_multi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                for (int i = 0; i < conn_list.Count; i++)
                {
                        await send_msg_multi(conn_list[i]);
                }
}
```

So, any idea for this, share with me. Thanks!

Comment: _"but seem not working"_ - Can you be a little more specific? How does it "not work"? What behavior do you expect and what do you observe instead?

Comment: Unless you have some specific requirement I would recommend using an existing protocol and library. There are plenty to chose from, http, gRPC, MQTT, RabbitMQ etc. These will likely be better than something you would write on your own. Raw tcp is mostly useful when you have no other choice, like doing schoolwork.

Comment: @Fildor, I have updated for more clarification, and what's my issue .

Answer (score 1):

Writing a decent socket server is *hard*; the best answer I can give here is "don't" - Kestrel (the asp.net web server) can act as a socket server, including full connection and buffer management build on an `async` core, leaving you just needing to write the actual protocol code. An example of this is given in [this redis-like server implementation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/main/toys/KestrelRedisServer), with more info in [this 4 part blog series](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html)

Comment: Although Kestrel shows as `obsolete` everywhere in my app. I don't know if it's the whole thing or just part of it

Comment: Kestrel is most certainly not obsolete (source: that's my team), so I'd need more context

Comment: our lead dev marked stuff like `uv_data` and `uv_idle` as obsolete. All i see is that it touches Kestrel. Hence why i said i don't know if it was the whole thing or just part of it. I barely touch that app usually just to rebuild as i am only in charge of a dll that it uses

Comment: @MarcGravell , assumed i forces used socket/tcpclient. I have updated my situation in this case.

Comment: @Headshot then to do this *properly* is literally thousands of lines of code; I have a helpful `SocketServer` type in Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial which is a quick way of doing this, but I don't have any examples of that to hand (you subclass it, override the `OnClientConnectedAsync` method, and use the pipe API to read/write data - `client.Transport` is the pipe)